# How can i insert html element between start and end tag of another html element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox :

```
    <input type="text"></input>
```

I want to add a span between the input element using jquery like the below:

```
    <input type="text"><span>Added span</span></input>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: That is invalid HTML. I edited it. Also, `input` consists of only one tag, and no closing tag. You can put a placeholder, or a value to have text in your input by default.

Comment: input tags hold text not more tags.

Comment: @Hidde it was not actually invalid _HTML_ (with the exception of `<input>` having a child? what is going on there?), but don't worry, I've made that same mistake many times and find the style really ugly so I'm all for the edit.

Comment: It wan't be visible if you add that

Comment: Use `<textarea name="name"> ... </textarea>` if you want a textbox.

Comment: @PaulS. Look in the edit history. The question was `<input type = "text >` and some more code. Very invalid.

Comment: @Hiddle spaces around the `=` of an _attribute_ is still valid _HTML_; try it yourself in [**w3's validator**](http://validator.w3.org/check) on `<!doctype html><html><head><title>-</title></head><body><input type = "text"/></body></html>`. The invalid bit is tags inside the `<input>` and the close tag `</input>` which makes no sense as an _input_ is a **void element**.

Comment: @Hidde: you are right.By mistake i made a invalid code. But after your editing it is exactly the way i want to write. Sorry for that silly mistakes..

Answer (score 3):

I will answer three questions:

**How to append some HTML in an element?**

Use jQuery: `$('div').append('<span>Added span</span>');`

**How to add a placeholder to an input element?**

Use the following markup: `<input type="text" placeholder="My placeholder" />` (Browser support: http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder)

**How to add text by default in my input?**

Use the following markup: `<input type="text" value="My text" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a `<span>` (or any element) into a text input. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GAFTk/

Your browser will change it to:

```
<input type="text" /><span>Text</span>
```

and render them side by side.

Comment: It will actually change it to `<input type="text" /><span>Text</span>`, just like there is no such thing as a `</br>`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to put html elements inside of input elements, but in general you use jQuery.append()

```
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>$("#demo").append("<span>added span</span>");</script>
```

Result:

```
<div id="demo"><span>added span</span></div>
```

If you append something else it won't remove whats already in there.

```
<script>$("#demo").append("<span>another</span>");</script>

<div id="demo"><span>added span</span><span>another</span></div>
```

If you want to overwrite whats already inside you'd use .html instead of .append, or .empty and then .append

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#inputId').innerHtml('<span>adding span</span>');
```

Comment: look at my comment at @matthijs answer

Comment: wow does someone even read the specs? or at least inspect their page with Firebug AFTER trying their answer?

Comment: @Dementic, why i need to look at the comment of matthijs? or one don't have right to answer?

Answer (score -1):

First:

```
<input id="inserthere" type="text"></input>
```

then:

```
$('#inserthere').innerHtml('<span>Added span</span>');
```

Result:

```
<input id="inserthere" type="text"><span>Added span</span></input>
```

edit: almost forget you can also use the jQuery "append" method if you want to ADD something instead of overwrite it!

Comment: -1 Not valid HTML, the purpose of this site is not only to help people, but on the way to teach them best practices.